# Email2Case: How to stop OOO replies updating cases

Tags: email2case

This might be a known issue but I am unable to find any answers at present.

When an agent sends an email from a case which includes the case thread, we are trying to stop OOO from triggering a case to be reopened if received back as this will create false stats.

Can anyone advise of a way that this can be done?

Thanks
Scott

Comment: I am thinking to look at the thread of the OOO to see if generic then it can be stopped this way.

Answer (score 4):

To fix this issue at the root would be to have your mail server configured in such a way that emails which contain key words, such as 'Out of office', are ignored. Although that would typically be an IT Helpdesk remit and not for a Salesforce Admin / Developer.

From a Salesforce Developer perspective, you can write a trigger which auto-deletes or prevents a new email thread hitting the case. This [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24812/is-there-a-way-to-stop-creating-cases-for-bounced-or-ooo-emails) gives some helpful information.

From a Salesforce Admin perspective, it may be worth researching an App on the AppExchange. [Email to Case premium](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001R5cyEAC) is very helpful for preventing email2case loops, but I am unsure if it [prevents email threading of emails](https://customers.internetcreations.com/s/article/Auto-Reply-and-Out-of-Office-Emails?language=en_US) which contain key words. Also from a Salesforce Admin perspective, although this isn't ideal, you can create new custom fields and have workflows / process builders created which would ignore calculating case open times etc from threads which contain key words.